# How to get daily totals from last week using PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM metrics 
WHERE tag = 'KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.BankTotalEnergyImported'
ORDER BY time desc
```

[image]

This is just a chunk out of all the data has been logged for the past 2 months.

What I'm trying to create is a query that gives me back a result of the total amount of the value column (SUM) per day of **only the last week**. For example:

```
 2021-07-08 - KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.BankTotalEnergyImported - 1234 - 5678 - 2791 (SUM of all the data from this day)
 2021-07-07 - KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.BankTotalEnergyImported - 1234 - 5678 - 1652 (SUM of all the data from this day)
 2021-07-06 - KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.BankTotalEnergyImported - 1234 - 5678 - 711 (SUM of all the data from this day)
 2021-07-05 - KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.BankTotalEnergyImported - 1234 - 5678 - 399 (SUM of all the data from this day)
 2021-07-04 - KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.BankTotalEnergyImported - 1234 - 5678 - 4219 (SUM of all the data from this day)
 2021-07-03 - KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.BankTotalEnergyImported - 1234 - 5678 - 6591 (SUM of all the data from this day)
 2021-07-02 - KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.BankTotalEnergyImported - 1234 - 5678 - 1848 (SUM of all the data from this day)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please tag properly your question. Is it mysql or postgresql?

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is basically aggregation with filtering:

```
SELECT time::date, container, project, SUM(value)
FROM metrics
WHERE tag = 'KEB1.DB_BP.01.STATUS.BankTotalEnergyImported' AND
      time >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 day'
GROUP BY time::date
ORDER BY time::date desc
```